# How to code software for automating purposes?

Tags: bots

I want to ask how can one write a software application which can automate browser processes such as logging into a site, posting some content and logging out.

There are a number of software out there in market which do so, but I am familiar with them from a long time ago, they need Internet Explorer to work.

I have searched a lot but could not find, in which language they are coded. Can some one put a guide or an article which will get me started on the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in any language which has libraries that "speak" the HTTP protocol. Most of them do. The implementations vary, from simple things like sending GET/POST requests, to advanced topics like automatic cookie handling and JavaScript engines.

The idea is to pick up a programming language you are comfortable with and start looking for HTTP library options it has.

Comment: I do not know that naming a software is right or not. please forgive if its wrong. I want to make a software like SEnuke or Facebook friend blaster.. They seem to be coded is C# or .net i think..

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make web scrappers/bots using [Perl](http://perl.org/). There are several [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) modules which will be of help.

For example, [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) module makes most tasks easy.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of CodedUI, SilkTest, QTP, Watin, Watir & other such software packages which can do this...

HTH.